# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 error displayed using python

Tags: python, try-except

I am a beginner in python. when i insert the record into the database. records are not added. I have a two columns in the database `id`,`name`. id set in mysql auto increment.

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector  # Importing Connector package

def Ok():
    result = e1.get()

    mysqldb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="empdb")#established connection between your database
    mycursor=mysqldb.cursor()

    try:
   mycursor.execute("insert into records values(%s)", (result,))
   mysqldb.commit()
   print('Record inserted successfully...')

  except Exception as e:
   print(e)
 
    mysqldb.rollback()
    mysqldb.close()

   raise Exception("Sorry, no numbers below zero")

root = Tk()
root.title("Employee Salary Calculation System")
root.geometry("300x400")

global e1

Label(root, text="Employee Name").place(x=10, y=10)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x=100, y=10)


Button(root, text="Cal", command=Ok ,height = 1, width = 3).place(x=10, y=150)

root.mainloop()
```

**Error displayed**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kobinath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/kobinath/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/employee.py", line 20, in Ok
    raise Exception("Sorry, no numbers below zero")
Exception: Sorry, no numbers below zero
```

I got the error above.

Comment: You silenced any error with your `except`. Add a simple `raise` to the block to reraise the exception for debugging. In general at least print the exception.

Comment: You need to know that the `raise` keyword is used to raise an exception. So you are forcing the exception. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i have to find the error for using the raise keyword

Comment: did you give `mycursor.execute ("insert into records values(result)")`

Comment: mycursor.execute("Insert into users (name)", (result)) yes You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Looks like your table name is called `records` and it has only one column. Are you sure the table has only one column. Can you assign a value of. say `'Hello'` to `result` and then execute the statement?

Comment: no sir we have 2 colums id,name. id colum i set as autoincrement in the mysql database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to catch an exception in python, you can use the following code:

```
try:
    x = int(input('Enter a number'))
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

This will help you find out what kind of error is occurring.

Looks like you are having a problem trying to insert data into a table.

Let us assume I have a table named `customers` and it has two columns `name`, and `address`, then I can write the following statements to insert a record into the table.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"

val = ("John", "Highway 21")

mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()
```

Then give commit to commit the record. If you have more than one column, it is important that you give those details in your INSERT statement.

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 error displayed

Comment: how many columns do you have in your table? records?   If you want to insert,  you need to give something like this `cursor.execute("Insert into users (name, email, username, password)")`

Comment: mycursor.execute("Insert into users (name)", (result)) this code Error   1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: That was just an example to show how to insert more than one column. If you have only one column, then you need to give `mycursor.execute ("insert into records values (result)")`

Comment: i tried above code i got the error 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'result' in 'field list'

Comment: can you give something like this : `sql = "INSERT INTO records (your column names here) VALUES (%s, %s)"` as many %s as you have columns. Then give `val = ("x", "y")' where x and y are your values. in this example it is two columns. Then give `mycursor.execute(sql, val)`. This will be the easiest way to solve it.

Comment: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s)' at line 1

Comment: mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO records (id,name) VALUES (%s,%s)") i put like this error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,%s)' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

In your code, this line

```
raise Exception("Sorry, no numbers below zero")
```

is executed anyway. Please check what you want to do and fix it.

But the reason you cannot insert a record is because of this:

```
mycursor.execute("insert into records values(result)")
```

Note that the whole string inside quote is executed as a SQL statement. Are you sure "result" is something valid in your context? This may have the MySQL raised an error. I believe what you mean is this:

```
mycursor.execute("insert into records values(%s)", (result,))
```

Comment: still record is not added into the database same error was displayed

Comment: inside "except", in addition to rollback, try to raise the same exception again